# Element missing after assigning the vector to another vector

Tags: c++

I am refreshing information about c++. In the example below I expect that v.size() will be 2. I try adding * before name but it wasn't good way. If Someone has any advice how to do, I will be grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Vector {
   private:
      vector<int> vec;
   public:
      Vector(vector<int> &v) {
        v.push_back(6);
        vec=v;
        vec.push_back(3);
    }
};


int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    Vector ob(v);
    cout <<  v.size();
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The misconception already starts with the first word of the title "Pointer missing...". There's no pointers in your code... what source are you using for your refresher course? Change to a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vec=v;
```

This will call the `std::vector` assignment operator overload. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D), this will...

> Copy assignment operator. Replaces the contents with a copy of the contents of other

So you're giving `vec` a ***copy*** of `v`. When you do `vec.push_back(3)`, you're affecting your copy of `v` that's now stored in `vec`. The two are separate vectors entirely.

Answer (score 1):

`ob.vec` will have size 2, while `v` in `main` will have size 1.

In the constructor, `&v` is referencing `main::v`, adds one element to it, then `vec=v` copies that into the member variable `Vector::vec`. From that point on, `vec` and `&v` are two separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines make a copy of v. Since vec is an independent copy of v, and the second push_back() is done on vec, only the first push_back() affects v.

```
vec=v;
vec.push_back(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the advice. After adjusting to them, I changed the code:

`vec -> 0x7fff60781670`
`&v -> 0x7fff60781670`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vector {
   vector <int> *vec;
   public:
      Vector(vector<int> &v) {
        v.push_back(6);
        vec=&v;
        vec->push_back(3);
    }
};


int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    Vector ob(v);
    cout <<  v.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what your program actually looks like, this seems like a broken program waiting to happen. If you have any other option, always avoid pointers when you can. *Especially* pointers to temporary objects like this. If you ***really*** need `vec` and `v` to point to the same object, you should use a reference: `vector<int> &vec;` and then the constructor would be: `Vector(vector<int> &v) : vec(v) { ...`.

Comment: Nice to know. Difference between pass value through pointer and reference is only semantic I mean some scenario where I can come across problems- on my example.